# batch/powershell script to restart a windows service on multiple servers one at a time

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I'm running an application in a *server group environment*. What I'm attempting to accomplish, is to create a `Batch` or `Powershell` script that will restart a specific service on each of the servers.

The catch here is that it needs to happen one at a time, so the Service on server 1 should restart, once the service is running again it continue to the next server. How can I accomplish this?

I've read many articles on restarting a service on one or many servers, but none on how to wait for the previous service to come back up before restarting the next.

Comment: "I want to do a thing I'm not telling you about, in an environment I'm not telling you about, using a general tool I'm being vague about. How?". Have each one look at the time and restart at 00:00, 00:05, 00:10... Have each one report to a central file share when it has completed and each one check for the server-name-alphabetically-before-theirs to report before starting. Have your central script computer, which you haven't mentioned, test the thing the service does, which you haven't mentioned, to identify when it's working again. `Start-Sleep -seconds 300`. Check the service status.

Answer (score 1):

```
sc query dnscache | findstr STATE
```

Result: (depending on current status)

```
STATE              : 4  RUNNING
STATE              : 1  STOPPED
```

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell:

```
if ((Get-Service Dnscache).Status -eq 'Running') {
  "running"
} else {
  "not running"
}
```